# Как поместить объект в рюкзак RobloxStudio

Tags: lua, roblox

Задача состоит в следующем, при касании к блоку, он должен помещаться в рюкзак игрока. На данный момент получилось это:

```lua
local function onHit(hit)
    local hummanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

    if hit and hummanoid then
        local copy = script.Parent:Clone()
        copy = game.Players.Alexandr23221.Backpack
    
        print("Cloned")
    
        script.Parent:Destroy()
    end
end

script.Parent.Touched:connect(onHit)
```

Я совсем недолго работаю с `RobloxStudio`, но идея была в следующем: при касании блок клонируется, после чего клон помещается в рюкзак игрока (хорошо бы, что бы его можно было взять в руки), а основной объект удаляется, но метод того самого помещения в рюкзак я не нашел. Скрипт написан на конкретно объекте. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!!

Answer (score 0):

Смотри, я тоже не очень давно работаю с этой программой, но могу помочь.

Если у тебя модель, а не tool, тогда не получиться. Но если тебе надо чтобы предмет был в инвентаре у персонажа тогда нужно создать парт, или уже созданный назвать handle, тогда его можно будет подобрать. Насчёт того чтобы он заново появлялся, советую найти в toolbox **gun spawner** и зайти в модель, удалить пистолет и засунуть туда свой tool (не знаю как у тебя он называется) и готово! Стенд с появлением заново предмета уже встроен.

P.S. Если надо чтобы он обратно не появлялся, создай tool как я и сказал и положи его в нужном месте и готово.